# Solve $f^2(x)=x+f(x+1)$

Tags: functional-equations

If the function $f(x)$ is such that
$$f^2(x)=x+f(x+1),$$
find a closed-form expression for $f$.

I found 
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+1+\sqrt{x+2+\sqrt{x+3+\cdots}}}}$$
is such an $f$. Does anyone have other solutions? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell you can define $f(x)$ arbitrarily in the interval $[0,1)$ and extend it from there according to the functional equation. This should produce infinitely many solutions.

Comment: You need to be careful here. Do you mean $f(f(x))$ or $f(x) \cdot f(x)$? Usually $f^2(x) \equiv f(f(x))$ and $f(x) \cdot f(x)$ is written as $f(x)^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always take either square-root, so
$$
f(x)=\pm\sqrt{x\pm\sqrt{x+1\pm\sqrt{x+2\pm\sqrt{x+3\pm\cdots}}}}
$$
Gives you uncountably many solutions...

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $f(0)$ is nothing else than the square root of the [Nested Radical Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html), which is yet unknown to possess a closed form. Obviously, if *f* were to possess such a form, then so would this constant, meaning your question is still open.